# Need help in AKS resource type which supports pod creation using ARM Template

Tags: kubernetes, azure-aks, docker-image

Problem Statement: I am looking for a resource type which supports pod creation using a .json file as we are trying to create a marketplace offer for Azure Kubernetes Service with our docker images running on the pods.

I was able to create AKS cluster using ARM template and Looking for a way to create pods running with docker images using ARM Template

> Expectation is to have a ARM template which supports creation of AKS cluster and pods running with specified docker images

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, you cannot directly create Kubernetes Pods using Azure Resource Manager (ARM) templates, as ARM templates are meant for provisioning Azure resources, not Kubernetes resources.

Comment: Thanks for the response @Grimlock, Don't we have a option to use Helm Chart in AKS arm template for pod creation as there is AKS marketplace offer by name "NodeJS Container on Alpine" which can be found using keyword kubernetesapps in Azure marketplace and they have deployed a pod with their docker images